# Slideshow css layouts interfere with html body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all I have 4 layouts in css which I wanna add a slide transition, first to second slide transition is ok but the second to third slide transition is not okay because if I add fadeIn or fadeOut effect in jquery the third layout for 1 second overlap the entire html body, and for 1 second I have 2 layouts on the screen after 1 second he looks fine in the normal position. If i dont add any effect (fadeIn or fadeOut) the transition is ok and it doesn't appear the overlap layout in the body!
Any ideas? 
Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
var nextSlide=currentSlide.next();
if(nextSlide.length === 0){
nextSlide= $('.slide').first();
}
currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
});
}
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.slide{
display:none;
}
.active-slide{
display:block;
}
.layout7{
float: left;
width: 970px;
height: 340px;
}
.layout7-2{
float: left;
width: 970px;
height: 340px;
}
.layout7-3{
float: left;
width: 970px;
height: 340px;
}
.layout7-4{
float: left;
width: 970px;
height: 340px;
}
```

Picture attached for visibility: [Link](http://s28.postimg.org/ixodfksp9/Untitled.png)

Website link for visibility: [Website](http://sorfilm.byethost8.com/)

Comment: A picture doesn't help because it's impossible to reproduce the problem...

Comment: Ok, I attached the link from the website [link](http://www.sorfilm.byethost8.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your fadeIn action after your fadeOut action is complete. I'm not able to test the code, but this should work.

Change:

```
currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
```

To this:

```
currentSlide.fadeOut(600, function(){
    $('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
});
```